# how to fetch menu from database with its subcategory

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii, menu

This is my menu

```
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="product-category.html">Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="product-category.html">Product 2</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="product-category.html">P 21</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product-category.html">P 22</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product-category.html">P 23</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product-category.html">P 24</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="product-category.html">Product 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="product-category.html">Product 4</a></li>
              </ul>
```

Product1, Product2, Product3 are categories from category table.
P 21, P 22, P 23, P 24 are subcategory of Product 2 in subcategory.
All category dont have subcategory.
category id saved in subcategory table.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcategory` (
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

How can i show it in menu by fetctching data from MySql with single query?

Comment: It is tricky to help with `SQL` without knowing the structure of your database beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please show me architecture of data base.In general it takes 2 cycles with a condition,first for category and second for subcategory.
file.php

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<?php
 foreach($array_category as $category):?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo $category['link'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></a>
     <?php  if( $exist_subcategory):?>
           <ul>
           <?php foreach($array_subcategory as $subcategory):?>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo $subcategory['link'];?>"><?php echo $subcategory['name'];?></a> 
           <?php endforeach;?>
           </ul>
           <?php endif;?> 
      </li>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
```

The only problem is the condition to enter the correct condition need to know to data base ahritecture.

Comment: Here you have relation many to many.
Do you need to create 3 table :
1.Table category with column: cat_id,name etc
2.Table subcat witch column : subcat_id,name etc
3.Intermediar table for cat and subcat : id,cat_id,subcat_id

Comment: And do you  check the intermediar table if exist subcategory for someone cat id

Comment: $query = "select * from intermediar where cat_id = $category['cat_id']";
$result = mysql_num_rows($result);//if is null cat no have subcat
$result ist condition for show or not show subcategory

Comment: You need use intermediar table for evite relation many to many in youre data base

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query by replacing your tables names and all specific details

```
SELECT * FROM `parenttable` p WHERE p.foreignkey IN (SELECT c.foreignkey FROM `childtable` c WHERE c.foreignkey = p.foreignkey)
```

Comment: this will give all fields